# Get the domain name of a computer from Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi

In my application I need to know if the computer is the primary domain controller of a domain, so I need to know the domain of the computer to call NetGetDCName function.

Thanks.

EDIT: The problem is related with the DCOM authentication so I need to know the domain to use the DOMAIN\USERNAME in case of a PDC or COMPUTER\USERNAME if I need to use the local authentication database of the computer.

Comment: C++ and WinAPI tags yet edited to make not-programming-related?

Comment: It does seem to be programming related, just a very simple question that might be mistaken for not programming related.

Comment: I need to get the the name using winapi, so is programming related. I think :s

Comment: Removed tag.  I can't yet edit the question to flesh it out, and that's a little frustrating...

Comment: Is it really not programming related or should the question just have more detail? 
"How do I pragmatically get the domain name of a computer?"

Comment: Pragmatically is nice, but I'd prefer to do it programatically. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would consider using [NetWkstaGetInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370663(VS.85).aspx) and pass the local computer name is that first parameter.

```
#include <Lmwksta.h>
#include <StrSafe.h>

WCHAR domain_name[256];
WKSTA_INFO_100 info = {0};
if (NERR_Success == NetWkstaGetInfo(L"THIS-COMPUTER", 100, &info) && 
    SUCCEEDED(StringCchCopy(domain_name, ARRAYSIZE(domain_name), info.wki100_langroup))) {
    // use domain_name here...
}
```

Comment: don't forget: `NetApiBufferFree()`

Answer (score 17):

The [`NetWkstaGetInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370663%28VS.85%29.aspx) function returns either the domain name or the workgroup of the computer, and is therefore not a reliable way to determine if the computer is a member of a domain.

The [`GetComputerNameEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function will help, used with the `ComputerNameDnsDomain` parameter, as shown below. This will return an empty string if the computer is in a workgroup, or the DNS name of the domain:

```
DWORD bufSize = MAX_PATH;
TCHAR domainNameBuf[ MAX_PATH ];

GetComputerNameEx( ComputerNameDnsDomain, domainNameBuf, &bufSize );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [NetWkstaGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370663(VS.85).aspx) Function do this.

If you pass in null for the computer name it returns info about the local computer.

It will return a `WKSTA_INFO_100` instance, which includes the domain name.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know if the machine the code is running is the primary domain controller I think your best option is [NetServerGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370624.aspx). If you pass *101* as the *level* parameter it returns an [SERVER_INFO_101 structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370903.aspx). Then look for its *sv101_type* member:

> **sv101_type**
>
> > The type of software the computer is running. This member can be one of the following values.
> >
> > > (...)
> > >
> > > `SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_CTRL`: A primary domain controller.

Comment: I need to know if the computer is PDC and the name of the domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific function to determine the join status of a Workstation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netgetjoininformation

THere can be 3 statussus, 'Joined' to a workgroup (The good old Windows 3.0 networking) status == NetSetupWorkgroupName, or joined to a domain status == NetSetupDomainName
or unjoined (standalone) status == NetSetupUnjoined

So if you know this, you can call the respective required functions in a reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have used this code. It works in local machine, executed remotely nStatus gives a ACCESS_DENIED error.

```
NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
TOleString oleServerName=strServerName.c_str();
DWORD dwLevel=101;
LPSERVER_INFO_101 pBufServer=NULL;
LPWKSTA_INFO_100 pBufWksta = NULL;

nStatus=NetServerGetInfo(oleServerName, dwLevel,
    (LPBYTE*)&pBufServer);
if(nStatus==NERR_Success &&
    (pBufServer->sv101_type & SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_CTRL))
{
    dwLevel=100;
    nStatus=NetWkstaGetInfo(oleServerName, 100,
        (LPBYTE*)&pBufWksta);

    if(nStatus==NERR_Success)
    {
        AnsiString strDomain(pBufWksta->wki100_langroup);

        m_pgServerConnection->SetDomain(strDomain);
    }
}
```

Thanks to all :)

Comment: I get ACCESS_DENIED also on local machine. It required admin rights to work properly.